# Sort React Admin ArrayInput and SimpleForm Iterator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I have a **ArrayInput** with a **SimpleFormIterator** with a Name and a Date as **TextInput**. The Output of the ArrayInput is sorted by their time of creation. Is is possible to change this sorting to the date of the **DateInput** field?

```
Example
1: Name: Test1 , Date: 19.02.2021
2: Name: Test2 , Date: 17.02.2021
3: Name: Test3,  Date: 30.03.2021

Example of what i want
2: Test2, Date: 17.02.2021
1: Name: Test1 , Date: 19.02.2021
3: Name: Test3,  Date: 30.03.2021
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across the same problem: I managed to sort this data witho .aggregate before sending it to the frontend